# What have i done wrong? (python help)

Tags: python, string-concatenation

The question i'm working on asks me to "write an expression whose value is the concatenation of the three str values associated with  name1 ,  name2 , and  name3" , separated by commas." 
"So if  name1 ,  name2 , and  name3 , were (respectively) "Neville", "Dean", and "Seamus", your expression's value would be "Neville,Dean,Seamus". "

The answer that i submitted is "name1,name2,name3" but when i click "submit" the message informs of a logical error within my code and that my expression didn't return the correct value. What have i done wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the code that generates the error?

Comment: current: "name1," + "name2," + "name3". it works fine separately on the command line but not online on the exercise page.

Answer (score 3):

Homework? Did you submit the result of the expression, or the expression itself?

`",".join([name1, name2, name3])`
Or whatever you used?

Edit: You  mention that you submitted ("name1", "name2", "name3") - which would not return the concatenated names - but rather those stings. If you wanted to do it like this (a little less elegant then the version I put above) you could try:

`name1 + "," + name2 + "," + name3`

The difference being the quotations (") around the names - are stopping you from using the variables provided.

Edit2: This is how I understand the question you were asked. They want you to submit to them, an expression that will return the values assigned to the name1, name2 and name3 variables (whatever they may be) - There are two examples of such expressions above - which concatenate the three name variables, and add a comma between them - have you tried submitting either of the examples above?

Comment: i probably indeed submitted the result of the expression when i should've submitted the expression itself. However, even when i made the appropriate changes i.e. i changed my answer to "("name1," + "name2," + "name3")", i still get an error. i tried it all sorts of different ways and it's not working. I typed my solution in the command line and it worked there..?

Comment: `"name1, " + "name2"` will output the string `name1, name2` where your question expects Neville, Dean. You need to use `name1 + ", " + name2`

Comment: sorry, i'm not exactly sure what you mean? "Neville, Dean and Seamus" are just an example for this question.

Comment: @Frens34 - Edited post to answer your question.